# Remove all "not equal" clauses from an expression

Tags: list-manipulation, inequalities

I am banging my head against the following question: how can I have Mathematica take

```
cond = 2 a >= 3 b && 70 a >= 19 && 20 a != 13;
```

and eliminate all the "not equal" clauses, returning:

```
cond = 2 a >= 3 b && 70 a >= 19;
```

?

---

Some background to my question. I am manipulating expressions that are list of inequalities, e.g.

```
cond = 2 a > 3 b && 70 a > 19 && 20 a != 13;
```

I need to convert such expressions to weaker forms, which geometrically corresponds to closure of the region. Replacing strict inequalities by weak is easy:

```
cond = cond /.{Less -> LessEqual, Greater -> GreaterEqual};
```

But I also need to remove all the "not equal" clauses, and I can't understand how to do this, or how I could even search for this in the documentation. Would any kind soul around here be able to help me? I found that I can do:

```
Select[cond, Head[#] == Unequal &]
```

which returns "20 a != 13". But then I'm stuck. I want the rest of the expression, not the "not equal" clause itself!

Thank you!

Comment: Does `DeleteCases[..., _Unequal]` do the job?

Comment: And try `DeleteCases[cond, _Unequal, {0, -1}]` if not.

Comment: Or DeleteCases[cond, HoldPattern[Unequal[__]]]

Comment: A more meaningful substitution: `/. _Unequal -> True`. It should work in any boolean expression, e.g. `a > 5 || a != b`.

Comment: All of these work! Thanks, everyone. I wish I had enough "reputation" to upvote comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cond = 2 a >= 3 b && 70 a >= 19 && 20 a != 13;
```

Replace the symbol `Unequal` with something else (which better be a function):

```
Replace[cond, Unequal -> (True &), {0, Infinity}, Heads -> True]
Replace[cond, Unequal -> (## &[] &), {0, Infinity}, Heads -> True]
cond /. Unequal -> (True &)
cond /. Unequal -> (## &[] &)
Block[{Unequal = (True &)}, cond]
Block[{Unequal = (## &[] &)}, cond]
```

Replace stuff with `Head` `Unequal` with something else:

```
Replace[cond, _Unequal :> (## &[]), {0, Infinity}] (* or _Unequal :> Sequence[] *)
cond /. _Unequal :> (## &[]) 
cond /. _Unequal :> (True)
DeleteCases[cond, _Unequal]
```

all give

> ```
> 2 a >= 3 b && 70 a >= 19
> ```

```
Replace[cond, {LessEqual -> Less, GreaterEqual -> Greater, Unequal -> (True &)}, 
       {0, Infinity}, Heads -> True]
cond /. {LessEqual -> Less, GreaterEqual -> Less, Unequal -> (True &)}
```

> ```
> 2 a<3 b&&70 a<19
> ```

Comment: `Rule`/`RuleDelayed` have `SequenceHold`, so no need to use `## &[]`--you can just as well write `Sequence[]`. I do prefer replacing it with `True`, though, particularly as this cannot introduce problems when the expression is only subjected to partial evaluation.

Comment: Thank you @Oleksansr. WFIW, while `##&[]` and `##&[]&` worked for `_Unequal` and `Unequal`, respectively, (similarly, for `True` and `True&`), i noticed `Sequence[]` and `Sequence[]&` did not.

Comment: Thanks! This is great. I can now not only solve my specific problem, but I have 10 slightly different ways of doing this, which gives me a much better understanding of what's happening behind the scenes in Mathematica's world. For someone like me who "grew up" on C/C++ and then MatLab, it's very confusing at first.

Comment: @Michael, thank you for the Accept. Welcome to mma.se.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the rule you' want is

```
Unequal[a_, b_] -> Sequence[]
```

I tried `Unequal[__] -> Sequence[]` but it didn't seem to work.

When mathematica sees `Sequence[args]` inside of some other head, it knows to splice `args` in place into the arguments of that head.  In this case, `Sequence[]` has no arguments, and so Mathematica replaces `Unequal` clauses with nothing, effectively deleting it.

Comment: This is because `Unequal[__]` evaluates to `True`.  Try `_Unequal` or `HoldPattern[_ != _]` instead.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the insight. I didn't know about this Sequence thing.

Comment: @Michael, sure thing!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, aha!  That explains a few pattern-matching mysteries I've experienced! +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
Delete[cond, Position[cond, _Unequal]]
```

Comment: This works, too! Thanks!